# WPF - Starting animation after another animation is finished in xaml

Tags: wpf, storyboard, wpf-animation, doubleanimation

I am using WPF and I have 2 storyboard animations. I want the second animation to start after the first one is finished.
How do I do that in the xaml code?

Comment: Do you know the duration of the first animation? If you know the duration then you can set BeginTime for the second animation so it will start after the first one.

Comment: Nice idea it works, but it there a better way to do it maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is possible in Xaml, if you can use some code behind you can do something like this:

```
 <Storyboard x:Name="MyStoryboard" Completed="MyStoryboardCompleted" FillBehavior="Stop">
```

and in your code behind

```
private void MyStoryboardCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var thing = this.FindResource("MyOtherStorboard");            
    var OtherSB = (Storyboard)thing;
    OtherSB.Begin();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is another way but not only in xaml.